# 3D biplot in Plotly in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization, plotly, pca

I want to plot something like a biplot in python Plotly ,but using 3 principal components so as to make a 3d plot.
[image]
How do I go about plotting the direction vectors(the red lines) of principal components in plotly python?

There is exactly the same question , but for R, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393823/3d-biplot-in-plotly-r).  I am not able to translate the code perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With much help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164909/plotlypython-how-to-plot-arrows-in-3d)

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
pca = PCA(n_components=3).fit(iris.data)
X_reduced = pca.transform(iris.data)
trace1 = go.Scatter3d(
    x=X_reduced[:,0],
    y = X_reduced[:,1],
    z = X_reduced[:,2],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=12,
        color= target,                
        opacity=1
)

)

dc_1 = go.Scatter3d( x = [0,pca.components_.T[0][0]],
                     y = [0,pca.components_.T[0][1]],
                     z = [0,pca.components_.T[0][2]],
                     marker = dict( size = 1,
                                    color = "rgb(84,48,5)"),
                     line = dict( color = "red",
                                width = 6),
                     name = "Var1"
                     )
dc_2 = go.Scatter3d( x = [0,pca.components_.T[1][0]],
                   y = [0,pca.components_.T[1][1]],
                   z = [0,pca.components_.T[1][2]],
                   marker = dict( size = 1,
                                  color = "rgb(84,48,5)"),
                   line = dict( color = "green",
                                width = 6),
                   name = "Var2"
                 )
dc_3 = go.Scatter3d( x = [0,pca.components_.T[2][0]],
                     y = [0,pca.components_.T[2][1]],
                     z = [0,pca.components_.T[2][2]],
                     marker = dict( size = 1,
                                  color = "rgb(84,48,5)"),
                     line = dict( color = "blue",
                                width = 6),
                     name = "Var3"
                 ) 
dc_4 = go.Scatter3d( x = [0,pca.components_.T[3][0]],
                     y = [0,pca.components_.T[3][1]],
                     z = [0,pca.components_.T[3][2]],
                     marker = dict( size = 1,
                                  color = "rgb(84,48,5)"),
                     line = dict( color = "yellow",
                                width = 6),
                     name = "Var4"
                   )


data = [trace1,dc_1,dc_2,dc_3,dc_4]
layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        title='PC1',
        titlefont=dict(
           family='Courier New, monospace',
           size=18,
           color='#7f7f7f'
       )
   )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig, filename='3d-scatter-tupac-with-mac')
```

[image: Output]

Comment: how do you plot this inline in a jupyter notebook? Really like the visual!

Comment: `from sklearn.decomposition import PCA` and `from sklearn.datasets import load_iris`are required

Comment: Also `color= target` should be `color= iris.target`